# How do you link to a place in another page without any styling issues?

Tags: menus, links

I have a 'Meet Our Team' section on my home page and I want to be able to click a menu button 'Meet Our Team' and be directed there, even if I click it from another page.

My problem is that if I use #meet_our_team as the URL, the link doesn't work from another page. However, if I use a relative or absolute path plus '#meet_our_team' (e.g. home/#meet_our_team), the functionality works but it becomes styled like the 'Home' button when on the home page (i.e. the button looks pressed).

This is because the CSS class 'current-menu-item' is applied to the list element.

Obviously this class needs to exist for the current element but how do I suppress it in this instance?

Comment: You could remove the 'current styling' by targeting that specific menu item - since you don't want it active on the home page, then there won't be any other page where it'll be current.  So just make your selector specific and cancel out the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple enough fix. Simply add the below to Additional CSS. On my first attempt, I didn't specify 'a' and so it didn't work

```
   #menu-item-1745 a {
    color: #5a5a5a;
}
```